# Which one has the closest meaning for the sentence?

Tags: expressions

I'm a 10th grade Turkish high-schooler. Today, we had the final English exam but one question confused me:

> **Choose the closest one for the sentence below:**
>
> > That red car is the least expensive one of all in store.
> >
> > > **a)** Every other car is more expensive than the red car.
> > >       
> > >       **b)** Others are less reasonable than the red car.

Which one would be convenient?

Comment: any thoughts? i'd go for b.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry hi! Our English teacher at school stated the answer as <A>. Thanks to it, I gained a distinction (100 points) in examination. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is A as B does not relate to the cost of the car..

> Every other car is more expensive than the red car.

This says that the red car is the cheapest.. It defines the object in comparison 'Every other car' and then continues to explain the context.

> Others are less reasonable than the red car.

This could be a multitude of factors why they are less reasonable.. Also it doesn't specifically mention the cars are less reasonable, there is more ambiguity here.

Good luck with your exam!

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Actually, I thought "every other car" in (A) stands for "the all cars inside and outside the store, all cars in globe" and "others" in (B) for those ones share the same place/environment with the red car. Thus, I presumed the answer as (B).

Am I wrong?

I'd really expect the two sentence to have the same subjects. I mean, "every other car" or "others" to be in both sentences.

Comment: @Berkant, I think you may have gone a little too far down the rabbit hole with your reasoning.. I am taking the question at face value `Choose the closest one for the sentence below`, the others in both answer is the reference to the car, but A specifies that explicitly.. Also reasonable would push more toward the `value for money` factor, instead of outright price..

Comment: If we used "Other cars" instead "Others" in <B>, would it make any differences for the right answer or new ambiguities/certainties for meaning?

Comment: @Berkant it still wouldn't matter, the answer A is still the closest definition to the original statement, there are multiple reasons for this. Specifically the matter of how expensive the car is.

Comment: Thank you for clarification the question. Today, our English teacher declared the answer as <A>. In this way, I've scored a distinction (100 points -- the highest mark in TR).